# How to suspend a process just before it prints it's output in C?

Tags: c, shell, jobs, signal-handling

I am trying to implement background jobs in C for my shell. The problem is it prints the output next to my prompt like this:

user@hostmachine:/.../$: [output]

I have now learnt that "stty tostop" helps suspend process just before it's output but that only works in a shell. I am trying to implement this functionality in C, so that it doesn't use my terminal during a prompt.

I tried to run "stty tostop" after starting my shell but it din't work. I also asked a related question before and now I am stuck here.

Comment: If your goal is just to have software not "use your terminal"... isn't that a job for redirection? It's not generally good practice to make software depend on its output going to a TTY at all in the first place, so relying on TTY-specific configuration is making things more fragile than they need to be.

Comment: (_oh_, you're writing a shell; it might be worth mentioning that in the question explicitly. Note, though, that conventional shells _do_ let background processes print data next to / after the prompt; in trying to do something different, you're liable to be breaking user expectations -- particularly, expectations that a background process will keep running without interruptions without any explicit attempt to interrupt it)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy redirect or do not output anything

Comment: @0___________ What if I want to execute "ls &"?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's true but not if I first execute "stty tostop" first. But this command does not work in my shell and I want some advice on implementing it. Or at least making it work.

Answer (score 3):

Processes in the foreground process group of a given terminal can write to that terminal without being suspended.  Others cannot.  Thus, to put a process in the background is to put it in a process group other than than one currently in the foreground ([`setpgrp()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setpgrp.3p.html)).

Use [`tcsetpgrp()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tcsetpgrp.3.html) to control which process group is in the foreground on a given terminal.  This is part of how you would bring your background process to the foreground.

You might find [Glibc's discussion of *Implementing a Job-Control Shell*](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Implementing-a-Shell.html) useful for more details and related considerations.

Comment: Could you give me an example in a code snippet? I am finding it difficult to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Evidently, @amogh, you did not make use of the links I already provided in this answer, especially the one that I specifically suggested as useful for more details.  You will find some appropriate example code there, plus a lot more information that you probably need to know to get this working.